# Find the area bounded by cissoid and its asymptote $x=2a$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Cissoid is defined with equation $y^2=\frac{x^2}{2a-x}$.

So we can see that it only has one zero, that is $x=0$, and that at it has a vertical asymptote at $x=2a$. To calculate area bounded by cissoid, we can take the square root of these equation. We get $y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2a-x}}$, $x\in[0,2a)$. To get the whole area bounded by this cissoid we will have to multiply area bounded by cissoid and $x$-axis by two. We have:
$$A=2\int_0^{2a}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{2a-x}}dx}=\frac{16a\sqrt{2a}}{3}$$
This is obviously incorrect, as it is known that it should be $A=3\pi a^2$.

What is the problem with the method I've used? Should this be done using parametric equations? If so, then how to find those parametric equations and after that how to find the area(though I could probably do that by myself)?

Comment: Your computation is correct.

Comment: @BobDobbs my computation is, but as seen in the answer below, my equation for cissoid isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of cissoid is $$\frac{x^3}{2a-x}=y^2.$$ Now with that expression you'll get the correct answer.

Comment: Can't believe I wasted two hours on this, just cause I was misreading it the whole time :)

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)